# Web HTML Form handling the data

Tags: php, html, mysql, web

I have created a form using html and the form basically gets the person's name, email, mobile number, and an option selected from a range of radio button options. I've looked at several tutorials, but I am still confused as to how I would be able to collect all users input data. Would I be doing php and mysql? if that is the case, how could i start? Thank you all so much!

Comment: https://scotch.io/tutorials/submitting-ajax-forms-with-jquery
This is a starting point

Comment: This isn't really an *SO* kind of question I'm afraid : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically here is how it works :

```js
function checkData(){
 var firstname=document.getElementById("firstname").value; // access firstname id field
 var lastname=document.getElementById("lastname").value;  // access name id field
 if(firstname==""){ // if first name field is empty
  alert("Please fill the firstname field");
  return false; // you don't send the data
 }else if(lastname==""){ // if the lastname field is empty
  alert("Please fill the lastname field");
  return false; // you don't send the data
 } else{ // else you can send the data to action_page.php
  return true;
 }
}
```

```html
<form action="action_page.php" method="post" onsubmit="return checkData();">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname"><br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

In your form I told that I'll send the data to the `action_page.php` file (which must be a .php file because if there is php, even a single line, your file must be .php) in the method `post` :

There are 2 ways of sending datas :

- get: the datas will be sent via the URL (in my exemple you'll have something like : `action_page.php?lastname=Potter;firstname=James`
- post: the datas will be sent and the user can't see them

in your `action_page.php` file you can access field using $_GET['nameOfFIeld'] if the datas are sent using GET, or $_POST['nameOfFIeld']. Again, in my empty you'll have something as :

```
$firstname=$_POST["firstname"];
$lastname=$_POST["lastname"];
```

Then you can do what you want, you get the 2 fields you have sent

This is just an easy example to show you how it works. You should learn more about PHP language if you don't know how to get the datas :

**For short** : in your form in the .html file you tell where and how to send the datas in the form fields (inputs that are not in the  won't be sent). A JavaScript function that checks if your datas are well formatted (check the length or if they aren't empty). The javascript function will return false if the datas shouldn't be sent, or true. Then in your .php file you can access name using the method like : `$_method['namefile'];`